# Unintentional looping in a .bat file

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

My code is really easy,

```
    @echo off
    cd C:\UVA\
    set /p file= Enter Problem Number::
    %file%.exe < test.txt
    pause
```

All it does is go into a folder where I put some competition files I'm working on and runs them using the test condition I save to test.txt.
Now I'm trying it on some practice problems that I know are "correct" as far as the coding competition is concerned, which implies no infinite loops and correctly stopping the program when input is complete.
But when I run this file, it appears if there is an infinite loop anyways.

I'm not exactly looking for an "fix" here, just advice as to something I may have overlooked, or a way to make sure the input file is read only once.

Comment: Get rid of `@echo off`, that interferes with debugging

Comment: Is `C:\UVA\test.txt` the test data you mean to run or did you instead want the `test.txt` from the same folder as the batch file? The only thing I can think of is the test case in that folder is causing a loop in your program.

Comment: Probably some problem of the program `%file%.exe` that you called.

Comment: Does it work if you run the commands yourself instead of with the batch file?

Comment: One comment about `cd c:\uva`, you might want  to add `/d` switch to it to make sure you really switch to that partition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but maybe you should use a `for` loop to read the data from test.txt, instead of `>` you could then just pass the arguments using the variable that is set from the `for` loop.

Example:

```
@echo off
cd C:\UVA\
set /p file= Enter Problem Number::
for /f "eol=; tokens=1" %%a in (test.txt) do set arg=%%a
%file%.exe %arg%
pause
```